# Athena date format unable to convert string to date formate

Tags: date, presto, amazon-athena

tried the below syntax none of them helped to convert a string type column to date

```
select INVC_,APIDT,APDDT from APAPP100 limit 10
select current_date, APIDT,APDDT from APAPP100 limit 10
select date_format( b.APIDT, '%Y-%m-%d') from APAPP100 b
select CAST( b.APIDT AS date) from APAPP100 b
select date(b.APIDT) from APAPP100 b
select convert(datetime, b.APIDT) from APAPP100 b
select date_parse(b.APIDT, '%Y-%m-%d') from APAPP100 b
select str_to_date(b.APIDT) from APAPP100 b
```

Comment: APIDT (1995-09-27 )  its in string type

Answer (score 22):

The correct query for parsing a string into a date would be `date_parse`.

This would lead to the following query:

```
select date_parse(b.APIDT, '%Y-%m-%d') from APAPP100 b
```

prestodb docs:
[6.10. Date and Time Functions and Operators](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html)

Comment: getting the following error when tried to excute the above select `INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "12633 " is malformed at "3 "`

Comment: This looks like an invalid format for a date. So . I would rather look at the input data and not the conversion of that data. "12633 " is in any pattern, not a date.

Comment: APIDT 
1995-09-27  (this is of type string in the table) I am unable to specify as date format and timestamp format for the column

I am getting the following error when i tried to specify the column as date
`FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Parquet does not support date. See HIVE-6384`

Answer (score 19):

The answer by @jens walter is great if you need to convert a column with a single date format in it. I've had situations where it's useful to have a column that contains multiple different date formats and still be able to convert it.

The following query supports a source column that contains dates in multiple different formats.

```
SELECT b.APIDT, 
   Coalesce(
     try(date_parse(b.APIDT, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')),
     try(date_parse(b.APIDT, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s')),
     try(date_parse(b.APIDT, '%d %M %Y %H:%i:%s')),
     try(date_parse(b.APIDT, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')),
     try(date_parse(b.APIDT, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s')),
     try(date_parse(b.APIDT, '%Y-%m-%d')),
     try(date_parse(b.APIDT, '%Y/%m/%d')),
     try(date_parse(b.APIDT, '%d %M %Y'))
   ) 
FROM APAPP100 b
```

The DATE_PARSE function performs the date conversion.

The TRY function handles errors by returning NULL if they do occur.

The COALESCE function takes the first non-null value.

There's a more in-depth write-up [here](https://cloudjunkie.io/all-articles/2018/3/25/parsing-multiple-date-formats-in-athena) (my blog).

Answer (score 14):

This worked -

```
cast(from_iso8601_timestamp(createdat) as date)
```

Comment: You sir, are a hero.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   b.APIDT,
         b.Appppppppp,
         date_diff('day',current_date, date(b.APIDT)) AS Duedays
FROM xyz100 a
WHERE regexp_like(b.apidt, '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}')
```

`WHERE NOT regexp_like(b.apidt, '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}')`
to exclude the junk date